# readWorksheetFromFile: endRow when first NA appears

Tags: r, xlconnect

I want to download an excel file online and create a database with it. Since the file is very polluted, I want to make the endRow dynamic, in the sense that R will consider the data until the first NA appears.

```
library(XLConnect)
tmp = tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
download.file(url = "https://www.dane.gov.co/files/investigaciones/boletines/emmet/anexos_nacional_emmet_marzo_2019.xlsx",
              destfile = tmp, mode="wb")
df <-readWorksheetFromFile(file = tmp, sheet = "6. Índices Desestacionalizados", 
                           header = FALSE, 
                           startRow = 14,endRow=232)
```

Any ideas on how to add endRow that is not a number, like the one above?

Comment: Most packages to read excel files will allow you to set a number of rows to read. Some of them will determine, automagically, how many rows to read, once they find a `NA`. The problem is the data **has** to be rectangular, so if another column has non-NA data at that row, then that row will be a legitimate one. I suggest you allow the function to retrieve the whole bunch of data and then do something to filter out the data you don't need / want.

Comment: Any idea on this part of what exactly to do to filter the data?

Comment: have a look at  `?complete.cases`, `?na.omit`, `?na.fail`. Those should get you started

Comment: Now, I wonder which `NA` you saw on the data... I went through all sheets and I didn't see even one: it's all sumarized data. Only problem I see with the sheet you want to analize is it's missing the column name for the field where all records are "Total industria". A simple `readxl::read_xlsx(pathToFile, sheet = sheetToRead, range = "A14:G232", col_names = FALSE)` should do. Only thing you need to do next is assign names (names are in painful marged cells)

Comment: Indeed, adding the range range = "A14:G232" should do for THIS sheet. But how to automatize this range so R stops reading when it encounters the first not data row/column?

Comment: `readxl` will automatically stop in the last row before *all* column values are NA. You'll have to supply first row information if you want to jump over the header image and merged cells, though. Keep in mind that some of the reader functions in different packages *do* consider as non-empty cells those that have been manipulated, even when only format (cell fill, text color, etc).